# How to implement Tap To Focus for camera in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

I'm working on a web application that has a custom camera screen, for which I'm supposed to implement tap to focus using `getUserMedia`

Here's the code:

```
 const permissionConstraints = {
       video: { 
       width: { exact: 1280 }, height: { exact: 1280 },
       aspectRatio: { ideal: 1 }, facingMode: 'environment' }
 };

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(permissionConstraints).then((permissionsObj) => {
        console.log(permissionsObj);
 })
```

Comment: Have you explored using [mediaTrackConstraints](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/#example4) to determine whether your camera is capable of focus control? Many are not.   I don't believe any getUserMedia()-accessible cameras have a way of setting the region of interest for focusing. You may be able to switch from `continuous` focus mode to `manual` and retain the current focus setting. Give it a try and ask more questions if you still need help.